# Screen flickering when battery low in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, power-management, battery

some days ago I tried to install nVidia drivers but nothing came up, so I reverted (or I guess so) to the "original" situation. Everything works fine (actually I don't neet my card, integrated graphics works fine for me now).
I've only one issue... when battery is low (20% and lower) my screen starts flickering bad when opening "new graphic elements"... What can it be?
When battery is above 20% (or so) I have no flickering at all, same when plugged to AC (even if battery level is low)

The command `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"` gives this back:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
```

Comment: I have very similar symptoms. Except I have 2 batteries. When my external battery starts to get low, I have to either remove the battery, or plug in in order to prevent the flickering. As you experienced, the flickering is worse when doing graphical stuff. Did you ever resolve this?
 I get the same thing when running `glxinfo`

Comment: I'm afraid i did not. I made certain that this was an hardware issue (my screen was flickering even during the boot splash screen of the manifacturer, or on windows, or in the bios screens. I've read online that the cause could be a loose connection of the screen to the motherboard or similar. By the way, I "solved" by changing pc, now I use a macbook, lol